# Multiple statements in a IF function

Tags: conditional-statements, lisp, autocad, autodesk, autolisp

Part of a custom command I have written I'm trying to have the IF function read thru 3 different statements but I'm finding out its not as straight forward as I initially thought it would be. I commented on the below piece of code what I would like each line to do. I'm wondering if there is a way to get this done thru an IF statment that I'm overlooking or if there is a different method I should be looking at instead.

```
 (if (or (/= flr "0_01.") ;if variable "FLR" is not 0.01 and
     (/= flr "4_01.") ;if its not 4_01, and
     (/= flr "6_01.") ;if its not 6_01...
     );if
  (progn ;then....
    ;repath an xref using the already established variables
    (command "-xref" "p" afile afilepathname))
  (Progn
    (princ "/n This is a model file") 
    );progn
  );if
```

I've tried using Cond to get this same result but I can't seem to find a day due to the "FLR" variable needing to be looked at and verified its not "0_01", "4_01", or "6_01" before the command can proceed any further.

Comment: Which programming languge and/or environment are you using? Please add a bit of context to your question.

Comment: I'm using Lisp to create a custom command in AutoCAD 2022. The short version of what this section of code is doing is its looking to see if a specific variable is one of 3 potential  options, if it isn't any of those 3 then it knows it will need to path a different xref instead.  The pathing part works fine, its just the IF statement portion that isn't working correctly because it seems to execute after the first  line of the IF statement runs.

Comment: `flr` can be only one value so it will always not be two of the values you check for and thus the test will always be `T`. Perhaps you meant `and` as it should not be any of the 3 values?

Comment: You can also use `(if (not (member flr '("0_01." "4_01." "6_01."))) ...` to make it easier to maintain going forward.

Comment: You wrote "and" correctly in the comment, but then you went and wrote "or" in the code.

Answer (score 3):

If I do not misunderstand your goal (reading the comments in the code), this is a logic issue. You should use 'and' instead of 'or':

```
(if (and (/= flr "0_01.")       ; if variable "FLR" is not 0.01 and
     (/= flr "4_01.")       ; if it's not 4_01, and
     (/= flr "6_01.")       ; if it's not 6_01...
    ) ;_ and
  (progn                ; then....
    ;; repath an xref using the already established variables
    (command "-xref" "p" afile afilepathname)
  ) ;_ progn
  (progn
    (princ "/n This is a model file")
  ) ;_ progn
) ;_ if
```

Or:

```
(if (or (= flr "0_01.")         ; if variable "FLR" is 0.01 or
    (= flr "4_01.")         ; if it's 4_01, or
    (= flr "6_01.")         ; if it's 6_01...
    ) ;_ or
  (progn                ; then....
    (princ "/n This is a model file")
  ) ;_ progn
  ;; else, repath an xref using the already established variables
  (progn
    (command "-xref" "p" afile afilepathname)
  ) ;_ progn
) ;_ if
```

Comment: Yup. (X not = a or x not = b) always returns true if a not equal b.